# Log data anonymization with ELK

Tags: data, logging, elasticsearch

I'm considering using the ELK stack for logging within our company. To comply with our data retention policy, we would like to anonymize data after one year so it cannot be traced back to an individual.

To automate the storage and anonymization: the following seems to me as the approach possible by ELK + ELK Extensions:

1) Logstash outputs **anonymized AND raw** data to Elasticsearch within **separate indices** (there will be a separate index created daily for anonymized data and another one for raw).

2) Using **Curator** extension with ElasticSearch, indices older than a year are  deleted thus only the anonymized data is retained from older periods.

The only downside of this solution, as you may have guessed, is that for a period of time you can say there is 'data duplication' when both raw and anonymized data are stored. The raw version of it will be deleted when it falls outside of the one year rolling window, but for a period of time - 2 versions exist.

Would be interested in your thoughts on this solution, and if there are any better approaches you can recommend? Ideally - just using ELK + ELK extensions and not building a separate orchestration module.